# FedEX home delivery shipping method does not displaying when total items weight in cart is grater than 70 lbw

Tags: magento2, magento-1, home, delivery

I am trying to display Fed Ex shipping method on checkout page, From admin home delivery option is selected and Residential Delivery set to yes.

Issue is when in cart items total weights is grater than 70 lbs then Home delivery option does not display, if weight is less than 70 lbw it displays,

Can any one explain why this happen or how to display Home delivery shipping method for items weight is grater than 70

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This link is useful: 
http://www.fedex.com/us/service-guide/choose-service/package-shipments/us-packages.html?qgroup=toggle-c2&qid=FedEx_Standard_Overnight

To display Home delivery shipping method on cart & checkout page,  calculates the sum of all the products weight in cart. Depend on  weight & distance it display home delivery option. So if the total weight is up to 70 lbs home delivery option display.

FedEx support Package Size and Weight Up to 70 lbs., 108" in length, 165" in length plus girth (L+2W+2H) for Home delivery shipping method.